# Blender 2.80 - Why can't I see Archimesh' properties?

Tags: add-on, properties, archimesh-add-on

I'm trying to create a room on a new installation of blender... When I press the N Key, I see the following on the properties window... The Teansform properties are showing, and the global properties are showing (this doesn't have any options in for Archimesh) but none of the properties for the actual archimesh are available... This is throughout all archimesh objects. Is there something i'm missing with this?

Kind Regards

Andy

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The archimesh properties are located under the "create" tab, the last tab on the properties menu :)